# analysis question- density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Prove that: If $N$ is a natural number and $c$ is a real number, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $V'_\epsilon(c)=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0<|x-c|<\epsilon\}$ contains no rational number $p/q$ with $|q| < N$

My thought is that all rational numbers can be listed as follows:
1/1, 2/1, 3/1 ...
1/2, 2/2, 3/2 ...
1/3, 2/3, 3/3 ...
.
.
.
1/N 2/N 3/N...

However, I have no idea about how to find ε in order to exclude all denominator that is less than N.

Can anyone give me some help? It's the first time I use StackExchange. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume $V'_\epsilon(c)=\{\,x\in \Bbb R\mid 0<|x-c|<\epsilon\,\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between two distinct rationals $\frac ab$, $\frac cd$ with $b,d\le N$ is
$$\left|\frac ab-\frac cd\right| =\frac{|ad-bc|}{bd}\ge\frac1{N^2}.$$
The last step follows because the numerator is non-zero (i-e-, $\ge 1$), and the factors in the numeator are both $\le N$.

Now if $c\in\Bbb R$, then there is at most one rational in $V_{1/N^2}(c)$. By makink the radios smaller, we can avoid this one as well (except when it is $=c$, but that doesn't matter either)

Comment: *except when it is =, but that doesn't matter either*. It does matter. It makes the result wrong, until proper definition of $V'$ is given. Right now the question is not correctly written and doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier ′()={∈ℝ∣0<|−|<}